# $\frac{1}{x^2}\ = (-5+\sqrt{3})$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, quadratics

How can I solve the equation: $$\frac{1}{x^2}\ = (-5+\sqrt{3})$$
I tried this:
$$
 x^2\cdot\frac{1}{x^2} = x^2\cdot(-5+\sqrt{3})
$$
$$
1=-5x^2+\sqrt{3}x^2
$$
$$
1= x^2(-5+\sqrt{3})
$$
$$
x^2=\frac{1}{(-5+\sqrt{3})}
$$
$$
x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{-5+\sqrt{3}}}
$$
Not sure if this is correct..

Comment: Your steps are all OK. You could have skipped over the one with $1=-5x^2+\sqrt3x^2$ -- there was no need to distribute the $x^2$ over the $(-5+\sqrt3)$ on the right hand side, since you pulled it back out in the next step. (As you get more experienced and comfortable with algebraic manipulations, you'll be able to skip more and more steps; eventually you'll be able to go straight from $1/x^2=(-5+\sqrt3)$ to $x=\pm\sqrt{1/(-5+\sqrt3}$ with confidence. But until then, include as many steps as you feel the need for.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Roots are imaginary as follows
$$\frac1{x^2}=-5+\sqrt3$$
$$x^2=\frac{1}{-5+\sqrt3}$$
$$x^2=\frac{-5-\sqrt3}{(-5+\sqrt3)(-5-\sqrt3)}$$

$$x^2=\frac{-5-\sqrt3}{22}$$

$$x=\pm i\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt3}{22}}$$

Answer (score 1):

This equation has no real roots because $-5+\sqrt3<0$

In $\mathbb C$ we obtain: $$\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5-\sqrt3}}i,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5-\sqrt3}}i\right\}$$

Comment: does it mean we can use complex number i to solve the equation?

Comment: @gaming patrickw I added something. See now.